# Webpack loader for returning CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I want to reduce critical path CSS by rendering some styles inline. Currently, I'm using CSS modules like this:

```
import styles from './Componentstyles.scss';

...

<div className={styles.cls}>
```

I'm doing SSR and I want all styles to be inline in SSR. I.e. for SSR, instead of using a class + an external CSS file, I want to have the styles in style attributes.

Is there an existing loader that does this?

The relevant parts of my Webpack config looks like this:

```
  {
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    include: [APP_ROOT],
    exclude: [/node_modules/],
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]',
        },
      },
      'postcss-loader',
      'sass-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
        options: {
          resources: [
            path.resolve('./src/styles/imports/variables.scss'),
            path.resolve('./src/styles/imports/mixins.scss'),
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```